# page.click puppeteer direct to another page does not work

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to go to a web page click login which will direct me to another website(which is Steam) to type username/password in. but when I click to direct me to steam it just hangs there.
my code:

```
try {
  await page.goto("https://www.tradeit.gg", {waitUntil: "load", timeout: 0});
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e)
}

try{
  await Promise.all([
    page.waitForSelector('a[href="https://steamtrade.gg/auth/steam"]'),
    page.click('a[href="https://steamtrade.gg/auth/steam"]'),
    page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })
])
} catch (e) {
  console.log("can not login, error: " + e);
}
```

the button I tried to click:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-3" style="color: #c7ced4;">
<a href="https://steamtrade.gg/auth/steam" class="mr-3" onclick="if (!window.__cfRLUnblockHandlers) return false; fireLoginEvent('navbar_mainpage')">
<button class="btn btn-success steamlogin my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit"></button>
</a>
</ul>
```

the error I got:

```
    can not login, error: TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded
(node:30861) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No node found for selector: input[type="password"]
    at Object.exports.assert (/home/danhle/Documents/Work/personalProjects/googleAdd/scrawlingApp/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/assert.js:26:15)
    at DOMWorld.type (/home/danhle/Documents/Work/personalProjects/googleAdd/scrawlingApp/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/DOMWorld.js:306:21)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async /home/danhle/Documents/Work/personalProjects/googleAdd/scrawlingApp/app.js:31:5
(node:30861) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
```

I really need help its been days ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, you make too complicated, try to keep it as simple as possible.

This code works just fine:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.tradeit.gg', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
    await Promise.all([
        page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle2' }),
        page.click('[href="https://steamtrade.gg/auth/steam"]')
    ]); 

    await browser.close();
})();
```

Even your code works if you change

```js
await page.goto("https://www.tradeit.gg", {waitUntil: "load", timeout: 0});
```

in a way where you don't wait for the load event.

Comment: oh I changed page.goto option to { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' } and I works thanks a lot man I actually don't know what the different between those options load networkkidle1 networkkidle2 even though i read the doc lol i am new to this